# python Questions about passing Python dictionary parameters

Tags: python

```
{
  "originProduct": {
      "statusType": "SALE",
      "saleType": "NEW",
      "leafCategoryId": "50002322",
      "name": "Jabra SPEAK 750 블루투스스피커/스피커폰/음성회의스피커폰/JABRA / 자브라 공식정품",
      "images": {
          "representativeImage": {
              "url": "http://shop1.phinf.naver.net/20221220_24/1671526069078ktTkT_JPEG/4172814067322311_1866531646.jpg"
          },
          "optionalImages": [
              {
                  "url": "http://shop1.phinf.naver.net/20221220_2/16715260691656YLKl_JPEG/4172814155176861_2054960625.jpg"
              },
              {
                  "url": "http://shop1.phinf.naver.net/20221220_5/1671526069249T4zWk_JPEG/4172814239069085_483270929.jpg"
              }
          ]
      }
}
```

I have a json file like the one above.

```
def open(self):
    with open(self.json_file,"r",encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        item_dic=json.load(f)
    return item_dic

def save(self,item_dic):
    with open(self.json_file,'w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        json.dump(item_dic,f,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)

def basic_data(self):
    
    item_dic=self.open()

    statusType = "SALE" #상품상태
    saleType = "NEW" #판매유형
    leafCategoryId = self.soup()["category"]["categoryId"] #카테고리넘버
    name = self.soup()["name"] #상품명
    salePrice = self.soup()["salePrice"] #판매가
    stockQuantity = 100 #재고수량
    
    basic_data = {
        "statusType": statusType,
        "saleType": saleType,
        "leafCategoryId": leafCategoryId,
        "name": name,
        "salePrice": salePrice,
        "stockQuantity": stockQuantity,
    }
    try:
        del item_dic["originProduct"]["productLogistics"]
        del item_dic["originProduct"]["saleStartDate"]
        del item_dic["originProduct"]["saleEndDate"]
    except:
        pass
    item_dic["originProduct"].update(basic_data)
    self.save(item_dic)
```

In the basic_data function, we create a json type and implement a function that loads and updates a json file.

I want to combine the def open function and the def save function into one so that they can function.

```
def save_func(self,key,new_data):

## key -> parameter like ["originProduct"] ##

with open(self.json_file,"r",encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        item_dic=json.load(f)

item_dic.[key].update(basic_data)

with open(self.json_file,'w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        json.dump(item_dic,f,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
```

The problem is that there is no problem if the argument to be passed as key is ["originProduct"], but when two or three are passed, there is a problem whether to get the key value inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it seems like you are looking to overload a function and update values in your `item_dict` based on what is being given to you. I will warn you, I am not used to overloading in python so there may be better ways to do this. However, I made a script that updates based on the data to be used as an example, but I am not sure if I am doing more than you need, but I feel that the answer is in there somewhere.

```
main_list = {
    "key1": 43,
    "key2": 54,
    "key3": 95
}


def update(param1, param2 = None):
    if isinstance(param1, dict):  # If parameter 1 is a dictionary, we have our key/data in param1
        update_from_dictionary(param1)
    elif isinstance(param1, list) and isinstance(param2, list):  # If parameter 1 and 2 are both arrays, we were fed keys in param1 and values in param2
        update_values(param1, param2)
    else:  # Assuming that if the above two conditions are not met, we were fed a singular key and value pair
        update_value(param1, param2)


def update_values(keys, values):
    # Handle updating your dictionary object by looping key/value pair using a for loop
    for i in range(0, len(keys)):
        main_list[keys[i]] = values[i]


def update_value(key, value):
    main_list[key] = value


def update_from_dictionary(dictionary):
    for i in dictionary.keys():
        main_list[i] = dictionary[i]


def main():
    print(main_list)
    data = {
        "key1": 1,
        "key2": 2
    }
    update(data)
    print(main_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the nice answer. However, updating the data key and value in the main() function is the second problem, and you have to start by finding the key value of a complex dictionary. Is there a way to pass only the key value as an argument when it is composed of multiple dictionaries?

Comment: I’m not really sure what you mean, I mean if you just want to pass a key, then it easy enough to just have a method with a singular parameter to be used for the key to be passed. Could you provide an explanation with an example of what you are trying to accomplish with any additional data structure for your complex and multiple dictionaries?